# Combining one faceted and one unfaceted ggplot2 in a row, ensuring the panels are the same width

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am in a situation in which I would like to combine two `ggplot2` plots together in a row. For sake of argument, Plot 1 is a single panel and Plot 2 is faceted into two panels. I would like to combine these together into a row of three plots, which can be achieved using `cowplot` / `patchwork`.

The key thing is that I would like to ensure each panel is the same width. Using the below code gets close, but the use of rel_widths still means that the actual plotting area of Plot 1 is small (I think due to rel_widths counting axis labels etc. and not the actual plotting area).

Is there a way of doing this simply? Setting the aspect ratio of the ggplot does not work.

The reason I am doing this is for two of the panels to share an axis but one to have its own. `ggplot2` itself seemingly doesn't have functionality to do this.

```
library(tidyverse)

plt1 = iris %>%
  filter(Species == Species[1]) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Petal.Length)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~"setosa")

plt2 = iris %>%
  filter(Species != Species[1]) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Petal.Length)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~Species)

cowplot::plot_grid(plt1, plt2, rel_widths = c(1,2),
                   align = "hv", axis = "l")
```

[image]

Comment: One option would be to switch to the `patchwork` package: `patchwork::wrap_plots(plt1, plt2, widths = c(1, 2))`

Comment: I couldn't get your example to work to test it but consider gridExtra::grid.arrange() as well.